# How to specify the presence of a point of interest that can be found while on the way to another point of interest?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence correct?

> There is a large mountain on the way to California.

Or should this be written as the following sentence?

> There is a large mountain one can see on the way to California.

I would like to know if both are correct, or only one is correct, or none is correct. If none is correct, what is the right way to write this sentence?s

Comment: Both sentences are correct, technically. Each one is a bit awkward, in my opinion. The use of "one" should be spare at best. Why not name the mountain? If you want your sentence to sound as if it comes from the mouth of a tour guide, why not spice up the sentence with a few descriptive words? I'll provide a few suggested revisions in my answer. Don

Comment: @rhetorician Yes. I agree. The sentences are perfectly correct technically and had they been "There is a newsagents shop on the way to the park" or "There is lovely painting you can see on the way to the exit" nothing whatever would have been wrong. It is just that in the context, the sentences sound awkward. They call for more information.

Comment: I would probably tend toward "along the way".

Comment: Grammar is one thing: meaning another. "seeing a mountain on the way to California"  is quite odd.  Seeing Las Vegas on the way to California by car....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a large mountain on the way to California.
>
> There is a large mountain one can see on the way to California.

Both sentences are correct, technically. Each one is a bit awkward, in my opinion. The use of "one" should be spare at best. Why not name the mountain? If you want your sentence to sound as if it comes from the mouth of a tour guide, why not spice up the sentence with a few descriptive words?

Some suggested improvements:

> - On your way to California, be sure to see the tallest mountain west of the Mississippi River: Mt. Rockalot.
> - As you drive west on Route _____, be sure to stop and take a picture or two of Mt. Rockalot.
> - Mt. Rockalot is a majestic mountain peak about 300 miles northeast of Los Angeles.
> - A must-stop on your way to California is Mt. Rockalot, the peak of which is snow-covered nine moths a year.
> - On your car trip west to California, plan to stop at Mt. Rockalot for at least a few hours.
> - While traveling in California, you should check out the tallest mountains  west of the Mississippi River (they are in the Sierra Nevada range, which is a chain of mountains along the California coast), the tallest of which is Mt. Rockalot, representing the highest elevation above sea level in the lower 48 states.